# Is there a way to guess if its going to rain based on pressure temperature humidity and cloud cover

Tags: meteorology

I am using a API to get historical weather information, only it is missing the probably and intensity of rain.

I do have this data:

- cloudCover
- pressure
- dewPoint
- humidity
- temperature

Is there a way to approximate the probability and or intensity of rain based on just the above.

Comment: Do you have this information for a single location, or on a grid for a large region?  Do you really not have time and location?  If you have time and location, you can “easily” get precipitation information by downloading a reanalysis dataset of your choice ;-).  If you really only have the above, then the answer is *no*.  Precipitation is more complicated than that.  Out of dewpoint, humidity, temperature, one can be calculated from the other two anyway.

Comment: Is it just surface data, or do you have access to vertical data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you live in a part of the world where the rainfall is dominated by frontal systems, and mainly by cold fronts, then there is a rough inverse correlation between pressure and rain. Otherwise, no. As Gerrit pointed out, rainfall is a whole lot more complicated than that. If you are looking for something to correlate with rain then I suggest you look into satellite-based cloud-top temperatures. The supercooled temperatures at the top of cumulus towers does correlate tolerably well with rainfall.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  Would change in pressure be any more of a more useful indication?  I.e. if there was a drop from one hour to the next?

Comment: Falling pressure is more likely to be linked to an incoming cold front, and hence with the rain that usually accompanies it.